# ThinkPad T460s touchpad jump

Tags: touchpad

I recently switched to elementary OS from Ubuntu, but have found that my touchpad on my ThinkPad T460s behaves worse with fine/precise motion. If I keep my finger pressed in contact and roll it slightly left/right, many times will not register as motion for a while, but then skip a few pixels ahead. This makes it hard to hit specific parts on the screen in a single attempt.

Is there a way to ensure continuous, precise motion? This is the only flaw I've encountered thus far, which is great!